# Show that $f(x)=x+1/x$ is a continuous function from $[ 1, + \infty [$ to $[ 1, + \infty [$ (Topology)

Tags: calculus, general-topology

*Consider the set $X=[ 1, + \infty [$ with the metric $d_{E}$ induced by the euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}$*.

*(a) Show that $(X,d_{E})$ is complete.*

*(b) Show that $f(x)=x+1/x$ defines a continuous function from $X$ to $X$.*

I'm relatively new to topology and have tried to solve this exercice but unfortunately I'm stuck. I proved $(a)$ but $(b)$ is causing me some trouble.

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a clear proof for $(b)$, I've already spent quite some time on it... I've tried to show that the pre image of every open set is open, but I wasn't able to conclude the proof.

Thank you all! I appreciate all help!

Comment: $x\mapsto x$ is continuous and $x\mapsto 1/x$ is continous then conclude

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $X $ is a closed in the complete space $\Bbb R $.

$f $ is continuous as a well defined rational fraction.

For $x\in[1,+\infty),$

$$f (x)=x+1/x>x\ge 1$$

thus 
$$f(X)\subset X $$

Comment: I think we have no right to use the derivative here.

Comment: @GuyFsone Ok i edited a new.